# React - Dynamically updating a Recharts bar chart?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm currently building an application that allows me to search records from a Google Sheet. Currently my program will compile and search records successfully, but it will not update the graph when I enter a query. I wish to graph the

I know it might have something to do with the filteredChartData, since that's what's being outputted in the graph, but my attempts to manipulate filteredChartData have been unsuccessful.

The code is shown below:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';



function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    headerRow: [],
    ncmr: [],
    date: [],
    customer: [],
    partNumber: [],
    model: [],
    rev: [],
    partDescription: [],
    sn: [],
    qty: [],
    defectDescription: [],
    supplierName: [],
    mrbDisposition: [],
    rma: [],
    status: [],
    comments: [],
    scar: []
  });  
  const [NCMRsearchTerm, setNCMRSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [partNumberSearchTerm, setPartNumberSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [statusSearchTerm, setStatusSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [partDescriptionSearchTerm, setPartDescriptionSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [dateSearchTerm, setDateSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [recordCount, setRecordCount] = useState(0);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredChartData, setFilteredChartData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const url =
      "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<insert details here>";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    const values = json.values;
  
    const headerRow = values[0];
    const rows = values.slice(1);
  
    const ncmr = [];
    const date = [];
    const customer = [];
    const partNumber = [];
    const model = [];
    const rev = [];
    const partDescription = [];
    const sn = [];
    const qty = [];
    const defectDescription = [];
    const supplierName = [];
    const mrbDisposition = [];
    const rma = [];
    const status = [];
    const comments = [];
    const scar = [];
  
    rows.forEach((row) => {
      ncmr.push(row[0]);
      date.push(row[1]);
      customer.push(row[2]);
      partNumber.push(row[3]);
      model.push(row[4]);
      rev.push(row[5]);
      partDescription.push(row[6]);
      sn.push(row[7]);
      qty.push(row[8]);
      defectDescription.push(row[9]);
      supplierName.push(row[10]);
      mrbDisposition.push(row[11]);
      rma.push(row[12]);
      status.push(row[13]);
      comments.push(row[14]);
      scar.push(row[15]);
    });
  
    setData({
      headerRow,
      ncmr,
      date,
      customer,
      partNumber,
      model,
      rev,
      partDescription,
      sn,
      qty,
      defectDescription,
      supplierName,
      mrbDisposition,
      rma,
      status,
      comments,
      scar,
    });
  
    const filteredChartData = rows
      .filter(
        (row) =>
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(NCMRsearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(partNumberSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(partDescriptionSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(dateSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(statusSearchTerm.toLowerCase())
      )
      .map((row) => ({
        qty: row[9],
        defectDescription: row[10],
      }));
  
    setFilteredChartData(filteredChartData);
  };
  
  

  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleChartData = () => {
    if (!data.ncmr) {
      return;
    }
  
    const filteredChartData = data.ncmr
      .filter((row) =>
        Object.values(row)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(NCMRsearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
        Object.values(row)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(partNumberSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
        Object.values(row)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(partDescriptionSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
        Object.values(row)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(dateSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
        Object.values(row)
          .join(" ")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(statusSearchTerm.toLowerCase())
      )
      .map((row) => ({
        qty: row[9],
        defectDescription: row[10],
      }));
  
    setChartData(filteredChartData);
  };
  
  
  const renderTableData = () => {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.ncmr && data.ncmr
          .map((value, index) => ({
            ncmr: value,
            date: data.date[index],
            customer: data.customer[index],
            partNumber: data.partNumber[index],
            model: data.model[index],
            rev: data.rev[index],
            partDescription: data.partDescription[index],
            sn: data.sn[index],
            qty: data.qty[index],
            defectDescription: data.defectDescription[index],
            supplierName: data.supplierName[index],
            mrbDisposition: data.mrbDisposition[index],
            rma: data.rma[index],
            status: data.status[index],
            comments: data.comments[index],
            scar: data.scar[index]
          }))
          .filter((row) =>
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(NCMRsearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(partNumberSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(partDescriptionSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(dateSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) &&
          Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(statusSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) && 
            Object.values(row)
            .join(" ")
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(partNumberSearchTerm.toLowerCase())
        )



          .map((row, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              {Object.values(row).map((cell, index) => (
                <td key={index} style={{ fontWeight: index === 0 || index === 1 ? 'bold' : 'normal' }}>{cell}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  };
  
  
  
  
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="search">
      <label>Search NCMR: </label>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setNCMRSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <label>Search Defect Description: </label>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setPartDescriptionSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <label>Search Date(Format should be MM/DD/YYYY): </label>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setDateSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <label>Search Status: </label>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setStatusSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
      <label>Search Part Number: </label>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setPartNumberSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
    <div className="record-count">Record Count: {recordCount}</div>
    <div>
        <button onClick={handleChartData}>Update Chart</button>
        </div>
    <div>
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
      <BarChart data={filteredChartData}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="defectDescription" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="qty" fill="#8884d8" />
    </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr className="title">
            {data.headerRow && data.headerRow.map((header, index) => (
              <th key={index}>{header}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {renderTableData()}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

and the JSON response from google sheets is:

`{ "range": "Sheet1!A2:AH920", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [ [ "#", "NCMR #", "Date", "Customer", "Part #", "Model #", "Rev", "Part Description", "SN #", "Qty", "Defect description", "Supplier Name", "MRB Disposition", "RMA #", "Status", "Comments / Remarks", "SCAR #" ], [ "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value" ] ] }`

Obviously there are more records than this but this is the format of the JSON, with values[0] representing the column names.

Why is the chart not updating?